# Getting the Difference between a date and system date android

Tags: java, android, date-difference

I am trying to achieve a functionality for a membership App but am find some difficulties working with Dates.

I retrieve a **startDate** from the DB which comes as "YYYY-MM-dd".
What I wish to achieve is to calculate the difference in day from the **currentDate** to the **startDate** store it in a variable **int result**

**if result > 365**
textView.setText("Membership expired");

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'll be really grateful.

Comment: Java.util.calendar is your friend

Answer (score 0):

you can use code below to calculate the days between currentdate and startdate.

```
(currentDate - startDate) / (1000*3600*24)
```